# How can I retrieve a user's public IP address via Amazon API Gateway (JAVA)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

Creating signedURL's using custom policy with help of Cloudfront and in policy adding client IP and expiry Date restrictions. To test my code I hardcoded my public ipv4 in the java code. How do I do this dynamically. I created a program

> URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
> whatismyip.openStream()));
>
> ```
>     String ip = in.readLine(); //you get the IP as a String
>     return  ip+"/32";
> ```

in local it is returning accurate output but while I am running it on my development tier it is returning cluster's IP and not user's IP. How do I get user Ip on my clusters.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the client's IP address in the `X-Forwarded-For` header as described in [the Cloudfront documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomIPAddresses).

A good description on how to extract the correct address can be also find in [How to get client IP of requests via CloudFront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393782/how-to-get-client-ip-of-requests-via-cloudfront).